# Custom multi-touch gestures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, multi-touch, gesture

I'm developing a web-app and want to use JavaScript and HTML5 for gestures. I came across this -http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/   , but for this we need Starlight browser (http://starlight-webkit.org/Starlight/).

I don't want to restrict users to a specific browser. For Firefox I found this ( http://felipe.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/multitouch-in-firefox4/ ).

So I was wondering if someone can point me to any resource that won't restrict me to a particular browser. My goal is to define custom gestures.

-AB

Comment: The example you give does not require multi-touch

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use these firefox resources but they didn´t work on my HP TouchSmart 300.

So here´s my solution:I´ve found my way using [TuioJs](http://github.com/fajran/tuiojs/) and [npTuioClient](http://github.com/fajran/npTuioClient/downloads) . This connects TUIO to your desktop browser. It works on firefox and chrome, didn´t try on IE.

Unfortunately, we cannot expect that an average user will set up TUIO just to visit our website, but anyway, it is a solution. Let´s hope there will be better solutions using HMTL5 in the near future.